# Sqlalchemy Find Intersection of two many-to-many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to using sqlalchemy and I'm trying to figure out how to find an intersection of two many-to-many relationships.  Given the following layout:

```
MediaPathRelationship = Table(
    "media_paths", Base.metadata,
    Column("media_id", Integer, ForeignKey("media.id"),
    Column("path_id", Integer, ForeignKey("file_path.id")))
)

AssetPathRelationship = Table(
    "asset_paths", Base.metadata,
    Column("asset_id", Integer, ForeignKey("asset.id")),
    Column("path_id", Integer, ForeignKey("file_path.id"))
)

class FilePath(Base):
    __tablename__ = "file_path"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    path = Column(String, unique=True)


class Media(Base):
    __tablename__ = "media"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    files = relationship("FilePath", secondary=MediaPathRelationship)


class Asset(Base):
    __tablename__ = "asset"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    paths = relationship("FilePath", secondary=AssetPathRelationship)


ses = Session()
path = FilePath(path="/path/to/something")
ses.add(path)
asset = Asset(paths=[path])
ses.add(asset)
media = Media(files=[path])
ses.add(media)
ses.commit()
```

If I have an Asset and I want to find all the Media that contain a path of that Asset.  What would that query look like?

```
asset = ses.query(Asset).first()
ses.query(Media).filter_by(Media.files.contains(asset.files))
```

Or something like that.

I thought maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721288/many-to-many-intersection-in-sqlalchemy) way related but not quite.

EDIT:

The best I've come up with so far:

```
paths = [p.path for p in asset.paths]
ses.query(Media).filter(Media.files.any(FilePath.path.in_(paths)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very close, try with:

```
ses.query(Media).filter(Media.files.in_(asset.paths))
```

Comment: I get a NotImplementedError when I try that:
in_() not yet supported for relationships.  For a simple many-to-one, use in_() against the set of foreign key values
I thought maybe I had an older version of sqlalchemy but it's 1.1.4.  So i'm a little lost.